# How to send data from Exele file to UWP SQLite after Generate an UWP package

Tags: sqlite, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, system.data.sqlite

#### I am using Microsoft Data SQLite NuGet package inside UWP App,

I have 300 record in Exele sheet after creating UWP app package  I want to send these 300 record to my SQLite database,how can I do that I even not know where is the database file and how to open it and how do I send these record

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this official document [Use a SQLite database in a UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases).

There is a small bug in the docs, You need to install ***Microsoft.Data.SQLite*** instead of Microsoft.Data.SQLite.Core.

Create a SQLite database in LocalFolder with `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`, the .db file will be created in your local folder:
**C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Packages\9be...(Your App Package FamilyName)\LocalState\sqliteSample.db**

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("sqliteSample.db", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

You can get the database through **Path**, and add your excel data with `SqliteCommand`.

```
string dbpath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "sqliteSample.db");
using (SqliteConnection db =
    new SqliteConnection($"Filename={dbpath}"))
    {
        db.Open();
        SqliteCommand insertCommand = new SqliteCommand();
        insertCommand.Connection = db;

        // Use parameterized query to prevent SQL injection attacks
        insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (NULL, @Entry);";
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Entry", inputText);

        insertCommand.ExecuteReader();
    }
```

Comment: We suggest you use [OpenXml SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-parse-and-read-a-large-spreadsheet) to load excel file content, and deserialize the content as objects within UWP, then write the objects to database.